# Перехват сигнала от потомка

Tags: c++, linux

Здравствуйте! Не судите строго, но я не могу понять, как узнать в родительском процессе о завершении его потомка. Знаю, что sigchld, функция signal как-то тут причастны, но не могу понять, каким образом родитель узнает о завершении потомка. Потомок что, сам должен слать родителю что-то типа "я завершился"(sigchld). А как это сообщение поймать в родителе? Помогите разобраться, что к чему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весьма подробно можно прочитать во многих книгах (например [здесь](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/unix/)) в главах про управление процессами.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте man wait, man waitpid и т.п. А информацию родителю шлет ядро ОС, которое и контролирует все процессы, их начало и завершение.